# Qt Thread object only sending signal as Qt:DirectConnection - why?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a class derived from `QThread`:  `class MyClass : public QThread`
This class is connected with a slot of another object. Originally this was connected as `Qt::AutoConnection`. But then - as soon as the thread is started (`MyClass::run()`) - the signal is no longer "reaching the slot" (**why?**).

```
// connected before myObject->run()
s = QObject::connect(
_myObject, SIGNAL(signalLogMessage(const QString&, QtMsgType)), 
this, SLOT(slotLogMessage(const QString&, QtMsgType)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

My first idea was that I need to force `Qt::QueuedConnection` (`this` / `_myObject` will be cross threaded). In this case it does not work at all. Only `Qt::DirectConnection` works. After the thread is started, IMHO `Qt::QueuedConnection` is the correct choice (cross thread).

**Any idea what is going wrong?** The connection itself seems to be correct, otherwise it was not working at (mean even not with `Qt::DirectConnection`).

Edit 1: -- As of hyde's answer / Nikos' comment

As of right now I think hyde's answer / Nikos' comment are pointing out the root cause. My `QThread` is running it's own message loop for another application. This is the reason why it is running in its own thread and is basically an infinite loop

```
run() { 
  // exec(); // while not reached    
  while (_runMessageLoop && ...) {
    hr = CallDispatch(.....);
    if (hr== 0) QThread::msleep(100); 
    // QCoreApplication::processEvents();
  }
}
```

Guess due to this infinite loop the Qt message loop is not running and no signal / slots are processed (is this correct?) When forcing `Qt::DirectConnection` the methods are called directly with no Qt message loop required, this might be the reason why this is the only connection type working.

**The question is now, how can I combine the Qt and my own message loop** (if this is feasible)? Cannot call exec() before the loop (because then it is in the Qt loop), and just the `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` in "my loop" is still not working.

=> see new Question here: [How to combine own message loop and Qt event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054053/qt-how-to-combine-own-message-loop-and-qt-event-loop)

Comment: The type of connection is based on the thread affinity of the two objects.  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads  Are you certain that the correct thread affinity has been established when you make the connection?

Comment: Is the event loop of your QThread actually running? If `MyClass::run()` is blocking rather than calling `exec()`, then no event dispatch can happen. Your QThread subclass must pretty much behave like a QApplication; it must let its event loop run naturally.

Comment: My message loop is no Qt specific message loop, but one for Microsoft FSX (flight simulator). Basically it is something like while(running) { dispatch fsxEvent; sleep(somems) }. Anything I can include to allow the event dispatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing all the code, but it may be because of this:

QThread object itself is not the thread, it's the thread controller. Most importantly, QThread object's thread affinity should *not* be the thread it controls. If your thread runs Qt event loop, then it's best to avoid subclassing QThread. Instead, have your logic (inter-thread slots etc) in another QObject, which you move to the thread you created with moveToThread after creating it. Only real reason to subclass QThread is to override `run()` method with one which does not call `exec()`.

Related reading:
https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

Addition:
If you override QThread::run(), you have to call `QThread::exec()` there or event loop won't be running and no non-direct signal gets delivered to any QObject with that thread affinity. If you want to have your own event loop, that is possible, you just have to call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) to process Qt events.

Comment: I have tried almost every permutation. MoveToThread, with/without subclassing QThread, connecting before / after starting the thread. Always the same. Communication breakdown after the thread is started. Nevertheless avery good hint and article.

Comment: Added stuff about custom event loop to my answer, based on comments under question above.

Comment: Thanks, I start to get it. Since I have my own loop, Qt's signal/slots are not processed. Updated the original question. Thanks so far for all your efforts, at least having an idea now, where the issue comes from.

Comment: This is the root cause and hence the answer to this question. QCoreApplication::processEvents() did not solve the issue, but the further discussion can be found in a rephrased question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054053/qt-how-to-combine-own-message-loop-and-qt-event-loop